# SSIS 2005 remote deployment of configuration file

Tags: sql-server-2005, deployment, ssis, configuration-files, remote-server

I have a dtsx package and want to deploy it to the Remote Test SSIS server.
I can import the dtsx file by using the import option on the MSDB folder through SSMS.

But i don't have any file access on the remote server so how do i deploy the config file to the test server file system?

If i run the manifest file on my local machine it wants to install both the dtsx and the config on my local machine.

How do i get the config file onto the server without local file access ?

regards

Comment: While you are deploying on SSIS Server (SQL), It will Keep Config file automatically to some default location on server.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are better off using a different configuration method instead of a file - maybe try SQL Server configuration & put the config in a table?

The only other option I can think of it to put the config file on another server & create a file share - provide the SSIS package the UNC path to the file share. It's a dirty hack though & introduces permissions issues & another failure point.

Comment: No.  I can't rewrite the applicaiton and certainly can't change the entire company policy on how configuration is to be carried out on SSIS packages.

Answer (score 0):

I've come to the conclusion that Config files in SSIS can only be deployed with File permissions on the server.  Something i doubt is given to developers in large organisations like mine.  So it has to be a two man job.  Me and a DBA.

I've also written SSIS packages for the sQL2012 environment where the entire deployment process is different.  It's not an issue as you can use project paramaters.  So i'm hoping it will become less and less of an issue.